# TYPO3 v10 Image Processing in Backend Environment

Tags: php, image, typo3, typo3-10.x

We recently started our first TYPO3 10 project and are currently struggling with a custom import script that moves data to Algolia. Basically, everything works fine, but there is an issue with FAL images, specifically, when they need to be processed.

From the logs, I could find something called `DeferredBackendImageProcessor`, but the docs are not mentioning this, or I am not looking for the right thing. I'm not sure.

Apparently, images within the backend environment are not just processed anymore. There is something called "processingUrl" which has to be called once for the image to be processed.

I tried calling that url with CURL, but it does not work. The thing is, when I open that "processingUrl" in the browser, it has not effect - but if I open that link in a browser, where I am logged into the TYPO3 backend, then the image is processed.

I'm kind of lost here, as I need the images to be processed within the import script that runs via the scheduler from the backend (manual, not via cron).

That is the function where the problem occurs, the curl part has no effect here, sadly.

```
protected function processImage($image, $imageProcessingConfiguration)
{
    if ($image) {
        $scalingOptions = array (
            'width' => 170
        );
                
        $result = $this->contentObject->getImgResource('fileadmin/'.$image, $scalingOptions);
                
        if (isset($result[3]) && $result[3]) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $result[3]);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $output = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
                    
            return '/fileadmin'.$result['processedFile']->getIdentifier();
        }
    }
            
    return '';
}
```

`$result[3]` being the processing url. Example of the url:

```
domain.com/typo3/index.phproute=%2Fimage%2Fprocess&token=6cbf8275c13623a0d90f15165b9ea1672fe5ad74&id=141
```

So my question is, how can I process the image from that import script?

Comment: Could you explain, why you need to process the image already during the import? 

Usually the contenObject renderer will be processing images with different qualities and sizes for the output channels based on a single source image. So it should be enough to just get the image, put it into the appropriate folder and process it later.

Comment: @JoHasenau I'm pushing the image url along with other data to Algolia. So the output does not happen in a Fluid template, but with Algolia instantsearch.js - so javascript. And here I need the already processed image (url), cropped to the dimensions specified.

Comment: As far as I understood the Algolia API, they process content based on JSON-data pushed to their service - so still this would be done with a specific frontend template containing one or the other custom view helper to process data on the TYPO3 side.

To me this sounds like a two step approach: First import data and/or images, then generate the JSON data for Algolia as a specific frontend output.

Comment: @JoHasenau But I would end up with the same problem. Even if I send the actual image path (non processed) to Algolia and process it later (which has to be done via PHP in some Extbase environment) I still would not be able to process the images. With instantsearch.js, you just simply output data. No additional rendering as this is pure JS, not PHP. So I will need the processed image path before rendering it.

Comment: The function you are using is a PHP function, isn't it? So what you are going to achieve obviously can be done with PHP. So it could be done with Fluid as well, since this will just create PHP under the hood, which will then output anything you want.

 IMHO you just got blocked by the assumption that it couldn't be done as a simple frontend output, so maybe you can describe the steps of the process a bit more detailed. Where is the data located, where does it have to go and what is the exact format to exchange that data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a more elegant solution but you could disable the deferred processing during your jobs:

```
$processorConfiguration = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['fal']['processors']
unset ($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['fal']['processors']['DeferredBackendImageProcessor'])

// ... LocalImageProcessor will be used

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['fal']['processors'] = $processorConfiguration;
```

References:

- https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/10.4/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Resource/Processing/ProcessorRegistry.php
- https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/10.4/typo3/sysext/core/Configuration/DefaultConfiguration.php#L284

Comment: That worked just fine! Thank you very much. :)